# Android - alert dialog appears momentarily than turns black

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm using a list view and the following code to show an alert dialog:

```
    exerciseListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(absActivity.this).setView(R.layout.layout_dialog)
                        .setTitle("are you sure?").
                        setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

The alert dialog appears momentarily like this:

[image]

than immediately disappears and turns:

[image]

Comment: what is there is layout_dialog xml file

Answer (score 0):

Apperantly the problem was in the emulator, after wiping the phone's data the problem was solved.